# CORS request not http when authentication MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, cors

I've read multiple answers on this topic, but none of them works for me so far.
I've tried changing the request on the client side:

```
const res = await axios.post(url,
      body,
      {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
        },
      }
    );
```

as well as configuring the CORS on the backend:

```
app.options("*", cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }));
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }));
```

The error message in Chrome is: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8000/api/user/register/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.`

On Firefox: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at localhost:8000/api/user/register/. (Reason: CORS request not http).`

What am i doing wrong?

edit:
I checked the req headers on localhost:8000 (the one i am fetching):
[image]

Looks like localhost:3000 is allowed, but it still doesn't work

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers must not appear in a request, they appear in the response, as decided by the server.

Comment: In addition to Heiko's comment: you've likely forgotten to specify the scheme of your target URL. Instead of `localhost:8000/api/user/register/`, try `http://localhost:8000/api/user/register/`.

Comment: http://localhost:8000